# Joomla Components are not working on webserver, but working on WAMP Server(Localhost), Why?

Tags: php, joomla, wamp

I am using Joomla1.5, Here some Components (TPJOBS) working very well on WAMP Server 2.1 (Localhost) but When I upload on Web Server , Components are not working .  Can anybody tell why this is happening , What changes I need in Web Server to run Components as they are working well on WAMP Server.

Comment: add this to your remote server options **set_behavior('localhost',true);** and try again.

Comment: where I should write on remote server. In htaccess file ?

Answer (score 0):

1. First Check the web-server version & your local-server version, there could be a problem with the server upgrades.
2. Better check the PHP version of the web server, most of the components+plugins works with the latest PHP versions.
3. Check the MySQL version and the Database content which you have uploaded.